# How to test whether a series converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've tried every convergence criterion I know. (Dalamber's, Cauchy's and Raabe's tests)

But in all cases, because of $-1^n$, I got indeterminate form.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \sin(\sqrt{n^2-1} - 1)$$

Tell me how to solve this.

Comment: Remark given as a comment, since it is **intuition** based, without formality.  As $n\to\infty, \sqrt{n^2 -1} \to |n| = n$.  No matter how large $N$ gets, there will be some value $n > N$ such that $(n)$ is **close to** being a multiple of $2\pi$.  When that happens, the absolute value of the individual term will approximate $|\sin(-1)|$.  Therefore, the terms in the series **will never go to zero.**  Therefore, how can the series possibly be (absolutely or conditionally) convergent?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: does the general term tend towards zero?

P.S.
BTW Dalamber's, Cauchy's and Raabe's tests are used with non negative series.